# ASP.NET MVC: store model data as JSON string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a (for the time being) self-learning project to create an Accounting Software package to manage Customer, Invoice, Estimate, etc. data.

I'm currently working on the Customer system. I know how to setup the application to store the different pieces of data in different columns, but I wanted to learn how to store everything as a JSON string.

Models:

```
[Table("Customers")]
public partial class CustomerDb
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Obj_Data { get; set; }
}
```

I then created a Customer model for the individual pieces of data:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public int Company_Id { get; set; }
    public string Customer_Name { get; set; }
    public string Customer_Company { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Phones { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Emails { get; set; }
    public string Terms { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Locations { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Preferences { get; set; }
    public string Exemptions { get; set; }
}
```

Add New Customer View:

```
@model BSheets.Models.Custom.CustomerDb

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Customer</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Obj_Data, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Obj_Data, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Obj_Data, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

CustomerController:

```
using BSheets.Models;
using BSheets.Models.Custom;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace BSheets.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        private BSheetsEntities _db = new BSheetsEntities();
        private ViewModel _vm = new ViewModel();

        // GET: Customer
        public ActionResult Index(string search)
        {
            _vm.Companies = _db.Companies.ToList();
            _vm.Customers = _db.Customers.ToList();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                AllResults();
            }
            else
            {
                FilteredResults(search);
            }

            return View();
        }

        public PartialViewResult AllResults()
        {
            return PartialView(Json(_vm));
        }

        public PartialViewResult FilteredResults(string search)
        {
            return PartialView(Json(_vm));
        }

       // GET: Customer/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            CustomerDb customer = _db.Customers.Find(id);
            if (customer == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(customer);
        }

        // GET: Customer/Add
        public ActionResult Add()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Customer/Add
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
       // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Add([Bind(Include = "ID,Obj_Data")] CustomerDb customer)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.Customers.Add(customer);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(customer);
        }

        // GET: Clients/Update/5
        public ActionResult Update(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            CustomerDb customer = _db.Customers.Find(id);
            if (customer == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(customer);
        }

        // POST: Clients/Update/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Update([Bind(Include = "ID,Obj_Data")] CustomerDb customer)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(customer);
        }

        // GET: Clients/Remove/5
        public ActionResult Remove(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            CustomerDb customer = _db.Customers.Find(id);
            if (customer == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(customer);
        }

        // POST: Clients/Remove/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Remove")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult RemoveConfirmed(int id)
        {
            CustomerDb customer = _db.Customers.Find(id);
            _db.Customers.Remove(customer);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

In a sense, I managed to make this work: the views to Add/Update customer information have a single TextArea where I simply add the JSON string. Then, in the Customer Index view, I deserialize the JSON string into a Customer object and display the individual Customer values. I then created a separate app with formfields using HTML/JavaScript to spit out a JSON string that I can copy/paste into.

If it were just me using this, it's perfectly fine as is pasting in the JSON string. Let's say I wanted to setup my application for a different user, editing a minified JSON string is cumbersome.

I'd like to create a view based on the Customer model defined above and submit a JSON string to the database from the CustomerController. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: In the first glance, I spotted `return PartialView(Json(_vm));` which is not usual way to return JSON string from viewmodel (`return PartialView(_vm)` is more preferred). If you want to return JSON string, you can serialize it first and use `return Json` instead of partial view. Can you clarify what do you want to achieve with `AllResults` and `FilteredResults` actions?

Comment: AllResults displays all of the customer records. FilteredResults displays customer records matching a search query

Comment: Why do you want to store JSON data in database?

Comment: It's for learning purposes only. I know it may be useful in some cases; technically it doesn't matter for this project and I could use separate columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a break from this for a few weeks, and I finally came up with an answer.
If I'm understanding what's going on:

In the CustomerController's Update GET action, I simply deserialize the input CustomerDb's Obj_Data property (it's the JSON string in my case) as a Customer object. I then pass the Customer object back to the view and it's working nicely so far (of course I bind the relevant model properties):

```
      // GET: Clients/Update/5
    public ActionResult Update(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        CustomerDb customerDb = _db.Customers.Find(id);
        if (customerDb == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        Customer customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(customerDb.Obj_Data); 
        return View(customer);
    }

    // POST: Clients/Update/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Update([Bind(Include = "Id,Customer_Name,Customer_Company,Phones,Emails,Terms,Locations,Preferences,Exemptions")] Customer customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(customer);
    }
```

There were a few things I had to change; for the customer model, I had to replace the Dictionary properties with separate string properties. For example, I removed the Phones Dictionary and replaced it with primary, alternate and fax string properties, and the Emails Dictionary is now a string. I'm sure there's a way to work with Dictionary properties, but every time I tested everything using them, I'd get a Null reference exception from them.

Then, some simple edits to the various controller actions to Add and Delete customer records from the database and it's working very nicely.

@Tetsuya Yamamoto, thanks again for the help.